# Is there a powerset equivalent to the Kleene star?

Tags: combinatorics, elementary-set-theory

For some arbitrary alphabet ***E***, is there an equivalent way to construct ***E**** using powersets, sets, or sequences?

Comment: Why the downvote? Care to explain?

Comment: Indeed, there turned out to be a great answer. It's a shame it is -1.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$E^\ast$ is defined to be $$\bigcup_{i=0}^\infty E^i$$ where $E^0 = \{\epsilon\}$ and $E^{n+1} = EE^n$.

Another way to define $E^\ast$ is that it is the intersection of every set $S$ such that $\epsilon\in S$ and $SE \subset S$:  $$\bigcap \mathfrak S$$ where $$\mathfrak S = \{S\mid \epsilon\in S \text{ and } SE\subset S \}.$$

Comment: $EE^n$ is meant to be the cartesian product?

Comment: No, it's the concatenation of languages.  $AB$ is the set $\{ab \mid a\in A\text{ and } b\in B\}$. Similarly $SE$ is the concatenation of languages $S$ and $E$.

Comment: Ah oke, thanks!